# Using if statement with in (findstr***)

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to do a simple batch file that find the key of a ini file to return the value of this key.

The batch is working find but i would like to check with a if statement if the str is not found Echo string Not Found.

Right now nothins is return.

```
ECHO OFF

set /p KeyIni="Enter the key of the value youre looking for: "
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr %KeyIni% system.ini') do set 
KeyAfterIni=%%a 

ECHO %KeyAfterIni% 
Pause
```

I already try a couple of thing like using the error level but its not working.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered that if the string is not found, `%KeyAfterIni%` will have no value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Not Exist "system.ini" Exit /B
:Start
Set "KeyIni="
Set "KeyAfterIni="
Set /P "KeyIni=Enter the key name to search it's paired value: "
If Not Defined KeyIni GoTo Start
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims==" %%A In ('FindStr /I "\<%KeyIni%" "system.ini"') Do Set "KeyAfterIni=%%A"
If Not Defined KeyAfterIni (Echo %KeyIni% Not Found) Else Echo %KeyAfterIni% 
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
set "KeyAfterIni="
set /p KeyIni="Enter the key of the value youre looking for: "
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr %KeyIni% config.ini') do set KeyAfterIni=%%a 

IF not defined KeyAfterIni ECHO Not found.
IF defined KeyAfterIni ECHO %KeyAfterIni%

Pause
```